# Inserting data into postgres db using shell script

Tags: shell

Unable to insert data containing character using shell script.
Below is the contents of my shell script

```
export PGPASSWORD='postgres'; psql -h 'x.x.x.x' -U 'postgres' -d 'postgres' -c 'create table luck3 (empId int,name char(50));'
export PGPASSWORD='postgres'; psql -h 'x.x.x.x' -U 'postgres' -d 'postgres' -c 'insert into luck3 values(9,'sam');'
export PGPASSWORD='postgres'; psql -h 'x.x.x.x' -U 'postgres' -d 'postgres' -c 'insert into luck3 values(6,'ram');'
```

The command works fine when the datatype is integer,but when I insert the data like 'sam' which is within the quotes,it throws an error:`column 'sam' does not exist`.

Comment: Use double quote `"sam"` instead of single one

Answer (score 0):

> export PGPASSWORD='postgres'; psql -h 'x.x.x.x' -U 'postgres' -d 'postgres' -c 'insert into luck3 values(6,'sam');'
>   You use semi-quotes everywhere in the script. So, it is need to escape it in the query:

```
-c 'insert into luck3 values(6,\'sam\');'
```

Or for better reading (understanding) use double-quotes for 'escaping' the query:

```
-c "insert into luck3 values(6,'sam');"
```