# Insert data into postgres using bash

Tags: postgresql, bash

I'm trying to insert values into postgres using bash. During my searching, I did find this:

[Inserting data into postgres db using shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53222779/inserting-data-into-postgres-db-using-shell-script)

The script I wrote is not working, and giving the following errors:

```
ERROR: column "task does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO my_table (task,date,quad,branch) VALUES (task,2024-0...
                                                             ^
HINT:  There is a column named "task" in table "my_table", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

My script is here:

```
#!/bin/bash
server=my_server
database=postgres
user=my_user

taskInput="task"
dateInput="2024-01-03"
quadinput="input_quad"
branchInput="shipping"
psql -U $user -w -h $server -p 5432 -d $database -c  "INSERT INTO my_table (task,date,quad,branch) VALUES ($taskInput,$dateInput,$quadInput,$branchInput)"
```

I'm not sure what's going on, and hoping you smart people can enlighten me.

Comment: Run your script with `set -x`, like this: `bash -x your_script`. It will show you what's actually running. The expanded SQL is incorrect, and the set -x will make that clearer.

Comment: Unfortunately, bash isn't a good choice of languages for this job -- there aren't facilities readily available to escape arbitrary data in a way that avoids injection attacks. (I wrote a client allowing use of bind variables in SQL from shells at an old job the better part of two decades ago, but it died with the company). You can make something that'll work for the data you have this moment without too much trouble, but making something work for _arbitrary_ data (much less deliberately malicious/hostile data!) is much trickier. See https://bobby-tables.com/ for some starter-level background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're building the SQL string yourself (and not using a library), you must provide quotes around strings:

```
psql -U $user -w -h $server -p 5432 -d $database -c "INSERT INTO my_table (task,date,quad,branch) VALUES ('$taskInput','$dateInput','$quadInput','$branchInput')"
```

---

Although this code allows an [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), it's clear this is an internal use only operational script and therefore "OK". I'm quite sure users of this script can drop tables etc without having to use injection via this script, so you're not really any less safe by the existence of this script.

Comment: If we want to demonstrate good practices, should also make it `-U "$user"`, `-h "$server"`, etc.

Comment: (...the other thing that's worth making sure the OP is aware is that this doesn't prevent against SQL injection -- if `branchInput=$'shipping\'); DROP TABLE my_table; --'` there's data loss in their future).

Comment: All - thanks for lots of GREAT information. Forgot to mention, this is a "quick and dirty", and a "for now" solution. Appreciate the input.

Comment: @Solaris_Guy How are you going to make this safe against SQL injection?

Comment: It's potentially possible to use `psql --set` along with `:` interpolation to improve safety against sql injection, but I don't have time to experiment with it myself, so leaving this as a comment.

Comment: @FrankHeikens - I need to address this issue. Needed a quick - "here, it works" solution. For now, I'm the only one running this script off my machine. Working on a node-postgres solution.